# Cannot connect to SQL Server Express named instance

Tags: sql-server, sql, database-connection

I have just installed Microsoft SQL Server Express 2014 (Database Engine & Management Studio)

I can connect to the default database using `localhost`, and it accepts the *sa* account password that I used to install the database

I opted for a "named instance" called `MSSQLSERVER` however I cannot connect using this instead of `localhost`.

What do I need to do,enable,disable etc. in order to connect to the database via it's name?

Comment: For a named instance it would be `computername\SQLExpress` where `SQLExpress` is the defaultname, you may choose another. Since you can connect via localhost computername or IP (if TCPIP configured) would connect to a Default ( not named ) instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not to clear how you installed the server, since you are able to connect via localhost I'd assume it's a not named Default instance.

A not named instance can be accessed via `Computername` or IP (if IP access is configured).
A [named instance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165614(v=sql.90).aspx) would be accessed via `Computername\InstanceName`.
To see which instances are available you might Start the [SQL Server Browser service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us_en/library/hh510203.aspx) and place an empty file on your desktop, rename it .udl and double click on the icon.
The shown dialog will list all available Servers, e.g.

MyComputer
MyComputer\SQLExpress2008
MyComputer\SQLExpress2005
ForeignComputer
ForeignComputer\NamedInstance

Answer (score -1):

`localhost` is not the named instance name, but the hostname corresponding with your local IP `127.0.0.1`. If you are in a network, place a DNS entry named `MSSQLSERVER` pointing to your servers IP. If you are local only, edit local `hosts` file and add an entry named `MSSQLSERVER` pointing to `127.0.0.1`. Do not delete localhost, it's an important entry in `hosts`. You can have multiple names pointing to the same IP.
You find the `hosts` file under `%WinDir%\System32\Drivers\Etc`